# Wicket 7 - AutoCompleted Text field - to have onSelect method

Tags: wicket

We would like to implement AutoCompleteTextField field, once user has selected the field from AutoComplete result, then system would auto populate on other text field, i have used the component AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior (blur), however this will take effect on every text input from AutoCompleteTextField  field, but if  i change to  AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior (change), it doesnt work.

Below is the sample code:

```
    AutoCompleteTextField<String> field_postcode = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("field_postcode",
            new PropertyModel<String>(getModelObject(), "wAdditionalInfo.postal"), autoCompleteRenderer) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
            if (Strings.isEmpty(input)) {
                List<String> emptyList = Collections.emptyList();
                return emptyList.iterator();
            }

            List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<Postcode> postcodeList = getProfileManager().findAllPostcodeByPostcode(input);

            for (Postcode p : postcodeList) {
                String postcode = p.getPostcode();

                if (postcode.startsWith(input)) {
                    choices.add(p.getPostcode());
                    if (choices.size() == 10) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return choices.iterator();
        }

    };
    field_postcode.setRequired(true);


    field_postcode.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("blur"){
          private static final long serialVersionUID=-1107858522700306810L;


          @Override protected void onUpdate( AjaxRequestTarget target){

              Postcode postcode = getProfileManager().findPostcodeByPostcode(field_postcode.getInput());
                if (postcode != null) {
                    City city = postcode.getCity();
                    State state = city.getState();
                    field_city.setModelObject(city.getCity());
                    ddl_state.setModelObject(state);
                    if (isDisplayTip) {

                    //isDisplayTip true mean is from widrawal webform

                        isReadonly = true;
                    } else {
                        field_city.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    ddl_state.setEnabled(false);

                } else {
                    if (isDisplayTip) {
                        isReadonly = false;
                    } else {
                        field_city.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    ddl_state.setEnabled(true);
                }
                target.add(field_city, ddl_state);

          }
        }
    );
```

Is there any api from wicket to achieve this? We need to have something when user select the option from Auto complete, then it only onUpdate method of AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/cbc237159c4c6632b4f7db893c28ab39d1b40ed4/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/wicket-autocomplete.js#L620 it should trigger `change` event on the HTMLInputElement and thus notify you on the server side.

Use the browser debugger to see whether https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/cbc237159c4c6632b4f7db893c28ab39d1b40ed4/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/wicket-autocomplete.js#L453 is executed and whether it leads to an Ajax call with the value in the parameters.